# Upgrade to Java 8 OpenJDK on EC2 using userdata

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, user-data

We are using an AMI that comes by default with OpenJDK 1.7
Using cloudformation UserData I need to upgrade this to 1.8 so that we can execute other processes that required 1.8

In the UserData portion of my cloudformation I have:

```
UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      !Sub
        - |
          #!/bin/bash
          sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

However, this does not work. When I do it manually there is an intermediate step where I have to type "Yes" to proceed with install, which I cannot do in this automated way. I haven't been able to find anything online w.r.t OpenJDK upgrade, only Oracle Java. Any help greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Karthik

Answer (score 2):

Found the way!
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel **-y**

I was missing the -y in the end.